# remove excess in time output using jQuery

Tags: jquery, time

Can someone advise me on how to remove the excess information in my time.

Here's my time:

> Sun Jul 27 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)

I want to remove the:

> 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)

How can I achieve this.

Here's the line which makes this type of format

```
var start = new Date(curr.getTime() - 60*60*24* day*1000);
```

Comment: You can build a string manually using the in-built date functions in JS, such as `getMonth()`, `getYear()` etc, or you could use a library which does this for you, such as Date.js

Answer (score 1):

```
    var today = new Date("2014-07-27 00:00:00");    
    console.log(today.toDateString());  
    console.log(today.toDateString() +" "+today.toLocaleTimeString() );
```